# The graph of $e^z$ for $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

When $|z|=1$(unit circle in complex plane), what is the graph of $e^z$? I know that this transformation makes a band into a angle area, but I have no idea about this .

Comment: See the [parametric plot](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28cos%28x%29%29+cos%28sin%28x%29%29%2C+exp%28cos%28x%29%29+sin%28sin%28x%29%29&x=0&y=0) section.

Comment: write $z$ as $cosø +isinø$ and see what $e^z$ is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $z=x+iy$ and the condition $|z|=1$ becomes $x^2+y^2=1$.

Now $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x e^{iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=(e^x\cos y)+i(e^x\sin y)$. Put $x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ for each $-1\le y\le 1$ (two times, once with $+$, the other with $-$) and your graph becomes

$$f(y)=(e^{\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}}\cos y)+i(e^{\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}}\sin y)$$